# Optimized way of doing string.endsWith() work.

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, arrays

I need to look for all web requests received by Application Server to check if the URL has extensions like .css, .gif, etc

Referred how tomcat is listening for every request and they pick the right configured Servlet to serve.
[CharChunk](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/CharChunk.html)  , [MessageBytes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes.html) ,  [Mapper](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.html)

Here is my idea to implement:

- Load all the extensions we like to compare and get the byte
  representation of them.
- get a unique value for this xtension by summing up the bytes in the byte Array // eg: "css".getBytes()
- Add the result value to Sorted List
- Whenever we receive the request, get the byte representation of the URL // eg: "flipkart.com/eshopping/images/theme.css".getBytes()
- Start summing the bytes from the byte array's last index and break when we encounter "." dot byte value
- Search for existence of the value thus summed with the Sorted List     // Use binary Search here

Kindly give your feed backs about the implementation and issues if any.

-With thanks, Krishna

Comment: Look up "perfect hash".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds *way* more complicated than it needs to be.

- Use `String.lastIndeXOf` to find the last dot in the URL
- Use `String.substring` to get the extension based on that
- Have a `HashSet<String>` for a set of supported extensions, or a `HashMap<String, Whatever>` if you want to map the extension to something else

I would be *absolutely shocked* to discover that this simple approach turned out to be a performance bottleneck - and indeed I suspect it would be *more* efficient than the approach you suggested, given that it doesn't require the entire URL to be converted into a byte array... (It's not clear why your approach uses byte arrays anyway instead of forming the hash from `char` values.)

Fundamentally, my preferred approach to performance is:

- Do up-front design and testing around things which are hard to change later, architecturally
- For everything else:

  - Determine the performance criteria first so you know when you can stop
  - Write the simplest code that works
  - Test it with realistic data
  - If it doesn't perform well enough, use profilers (etc) to work out where the bottleneck is, and optimize that making sure that you can *prove* the benefits using your existing tests

Comment: The first rule of optimization: Don't do it. It's mosten times correct.